# How I say in English with the correct grammar "This is the solution that I searched"

Tags: grammar, british-english

How I say with the correct grammar in English "This is the solution that I searched?"

I think the verb searched didn't is the correct conjugation of the verb

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the "This is the solution that I searched"  Why do you think this is not correct.  Please give details.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: "This is the solution I found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *solution* is a bit formal. Also "that I searched" is somewhat stilted, and, like *solution*, *searched* is a bit too formal.

All told, if you want to sound more natural, you would say something like this:

> That's the answer I was looking for.

---

If you actually want to preserve the level of formality of the phrase in the question, the following would be more likely:

> This is the solution I sought.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the your clarification

Answer (score 1):

In English, you search *somewhere* or *some place* **for** something. The object you're trying to find goes with the preposition "for". In your sentence "solution" is what you were trying to find. Therefore the correct way to say it is

This is the solution that I searched for.

Compare with: This is the room that I searched.

Comment: If I searched for the solution to the problem? or if I'm searching for a solution to the problem and you help me to search it? I can say to "Thanks, this is the solution that I searched for"?